# Do all template instantiations generate a new class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

So one of the most common examples of template metaprogramming is calculating the N-th fibonacci number like so:

```
template <int T>
struct Fibonacci
{
    enum { value = (Fibonacci<T - 1>::value + Fibonacci<T - 2>::value) };
};

template <>
struct Fibonacci<0>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template <>
struct Fibonacci<1>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template <>
struct Fibonacci<2>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

int main()
{
    cout << Fibonacci<45>::value << endl;
}
```

This is cool, but what if you call `Fibonacci<N>` for 100 different values of `N`. Won't the compiler generate 100 different versions of `Fibonacci`, blowing up the size of the executable? Are the rules of class generation different for `typename` vs `int` (or some other data type) or are they the same i.e. one class generate per unique combination of template parameters?

Would `constexpr` yield better executable size/compiler performance?

Comment: It will not blow up the size of the executable, as Fibonacci does not contain any functions.  But you may try to compile it and look how does the size of object file (.o under Unix) depend on this "45" number.

Comment: @user31264 but it does indeed generate a new `Fibonacci` class for each instantiation? Imagine if `Fibonacci` were instead a super complex class; this would definitely increase the executable size, right?

Comment: You may be surprised how deep modern optimizers can take this: [example here](https://godbolt.org/g/tukRTj).

Comment: @WhozCraig But despite the optimizations, unique code is produced for each case of of `Fibonacci<N>` being used, whether it be a simple `mov` or construction of a unique class. So the compiler, while it can reuse as much code as possible, it still hits a fundamental limit right?

Comment: Certainly it does. It isn't turtles all the way down. It certainly taxes the *compiler*, and all the components therein. There is no free ride. Recursive expansion has limits, for example. My clang has a 128-depth limit (last I checked).

Comment: @rcplusplus even if it would be super-complex class, its member functions would not be generated if no one would call it.